# Double number of columns while making it ^2

Tags: r

I want to double my columns while multiplying by the power of 2 (^2). I'd like to find a more intuitive way to do it.

For replication:

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(V1 = c(0.174, 0.0149, 0.3701, 0.0996), V2 = c(9.438279, 
10.038886, 33.23827, 5.912603), V3 = c(33.744, 24.534, 86.275, 
13.98), V4 = c(2490, 192, 159, 26.01), V5 = c(606, 68, 47.2, 
299)), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), class = "data.frame")

> df
        V1        V2     V3      V4    V5
1  0.1740  9.438279 33.744 2490.00 606.0
2  0.0149 10.038886 24.534  192.00  68.0
3  0.3701 33.238270 86.275  159.00  47.2
4  0.0996  5.912603 13.980   26.01 299.0
```

And that's how I've been doing until now:

```
df$V1_2 <- df$V1^2
df$V2_2 <- df$V2^2
df$V3_2 <- df$V3^2
...
```

Any tips on how to do this at once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use this directly on the dataset

```
df[paste0(names(df), "_2")] <- df^2
```

---

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   mutate_all(list(`2` = ~ .^2))
#  V1        V2     V3      V4    V5       V1_2       V2_2      V3_2         V4_2      V5_2
#1 0.1740  9.438279 33.744 2490.00 606.0 0.03027600   89.08111 1138.6575 6200100.0000 367236.00
#2 0.0149 10.038886 24.534  192.00  68.0 0.00022201  100.77923  601.9172   36864.0000   4624.00
#3 0.3701 33.238270 86.275  159.00  47.2 0.13697401 1104.78259 7443.3756   25281.0000   2227.84
#4 0.0996  5.912603 13.980   26.01 299.0 0.00992016   34.95887  195.4404     676.5201  89401.00
```